# CloudKit does not work with Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, ios-simulator, cloudkit

Recently I've been having trouble getting the iOS Simulator to work with the records I've made in the CloudKit Dashboard. The interesting thing is that it works with a real device, but not with the simulator. CloudKit Dashboard says that it is a development environment. When I run my app with the simulator I get one of these two errors:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)" (connection to service named com.apple.cloudd) UserInfo=0x7a276d40 {NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.cloudd}

or I get

> Error : CKError 0x7b658890: "Request Rate Limited" (7/2008); "This operation has been rate limited"; Retry after 3.0 seconds

Any idea of what is causing this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to sign into iCloud on your simulator.  Go to settings, iCloud, and enter your iCloud credentials.

Comment: What if it won't accept my credentials? I'm trying to log in with my developer account.

Comment: The issue was that the developer account would not be accepted as an iCloud account, instead I had to use my personal iCloud account. I'm not sure why that is, but it works now.

Comment: Doesn't work with my iCloud account and i'm not willing to change. IMHO this is a bug (at leat not a feature).

Comment: @brainray Can you clarify? iCloud is supported in the Sim. You must go into Settings in the Sim and sign in with the account you want to use.

Comment: @russbishop  In early versions there have been bugs logging in.